# For two complex number $z_1,z_2 $, if $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$ then what is the value of $Arg(z_1)-Arg(z_2)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I rewrote $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $Arg(z) =  \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$. But I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\tag1
|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+2\operatorname{Re}z_1\overline{z_2},
$$
and
$$\tag2
(|z_1|+|z_2|)^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+2|z_1|\,|z_2|. 
$$
As this two quantities are equal, we get that
$$\tag3
\operatorname{Re}z_1\overline{z_2}=|z_1|\,|z_2|. 
$$
If we write $z_1=re^{i\theta}$, $z_2=se^{i\omega}$, $(3)$ becomes
$$
rs\,e^{i(\theta-\omega)}=rs.
$$
Assuming that $rs\ne0$ (if one of $z_1,z_2$ is zero then you cannot say anything about the argument of the other one),
$$
e^{i(\theta-\omega)}=1.
$$
Which gives you
$$
\theta-\omega=2k\pi,\qquad k\in\mathbb Z. 
$$